# Save Values of Dynamically created TextBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

guys i am creating dynamic TextBoxes everytime a button is clicked. but once i have as many text boxes as i want.. i want to save these value Database Table.. Please guide how to save it into DB

```
public void addmoreCustom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["addmoreEdu"] != null)
    {
        myCount = (int)ViewState["addmoreEdu"];
    }
    myCount++;
    ViewState["addmoreEdu"] = myCount;
    //dynamicTextBoxes = new TextBox[myCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < myCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtboxcustom = new TextBox();
        Literal newlit = new Literal();
        newlit.Text = "<br /><br />";
        txtboxcustom.ID = "txtBoxcustom" + i.ToString();
        myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(txtboxcustom);
        myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newlit);
        dynamicTextBoxes = new TextBox[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try something?

Comment: not yet. thinking about few... but not sure.

Comment: take one from few, apply it to your code then question here..because at that time we have a specific question to troubleshoot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate the dynamical controls in `Page_Load` at the latest, otherwise the `ViewState` is not loaded correctly. You can however add a new dynamical control in an event handler(which happens after page_load in the page's lifefycle).

So `addmoreCustom_Click` is too late for the recreation of all already created controls, but it's not tool late to add a new control or to read the `Text`.

So something like this should work(untested):

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["addmoreEdu"] != null)
    {
        myCount = (int)ViewState["addmoreEdu"];
    }

    addControls(myCount);
}

public void addmoreCustom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["addmoreEdu"] != null)
    {
        myCount = (int)ViewState["addmoreEdu"];
    }
    myCount++;
    ViewState["addmoreEdu"] = myCount;

    addControls(1);
}

private void addControls(int count)
{
    int txtCount = myPlaceHolder.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtboxcustom = new TextBox();
        Literal newlit = new Literal();
        newlit.Text = "<br /><br />";
        txtboxcustom.ID = "txtBoxcustom" + txtCount.ToString();
        myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(txtboxcustom);
        myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newlit);
    }
}
```

Just enumerate the `PlaceHolder`-Controls to find your `TextBoxes` or use Linq:

```
private void saveData()
{
    foreach (TextBox txt in myPlaceHolder.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        string text = txt.Text;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: textboxes are based on buton click view states,, so if the button is clicked 5 times it will generate 5 Textboxes,, let say i have 5 text boxes and i fill in the information in all 5 ... how can i read the text of these 5 text boxes so i can send it to DB

Comment: @user2104029: Just enumerate the `TextBoxes` in the `PlaceHoder` and use the `Text` property.

Comment: ,, my concern is how can i read the text of these texttboxes.. please can you write loop who will iterate through these textboxes

Comment: @user2104029: Edited my answer to show you how to find the textboxes. Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` for `Enumerable.OfType`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way would be to just iterate the Form collection  looking for proper values:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string name = "txtBoxcustom";
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        int index = key.IndexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            int num = Int32.Parse(key.Substring(index + name.Length));
            string value = Request.Form[key];
            //store value of txtBoxcustom with that number to database...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get values of dynamically created controls on postback you need to recreate those controls on Page_Init event
Then view state of those controls will be loaded and you will get controls and there values.

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
addControls(myCount);
}
```

I hope this will resolve your problem
Happy coding